# .net razor web.config namespaces tag reference to models not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to include a reference to my models in a .net page. I have referred to the models in my Web.Config namespaces tag. Here is the part of my Web.Config where I have referred to the models:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="LangSiteMvc" />
        <add namespace="LangSiteMvc.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Here is a screenshot of my models:
[image]

But when I try to make my model `List<CalendarModel>` Intellisense doesn't recognize it:

[image]

However when I add a using statement to the page it does:
[image]

I don't want to have to add a using statement to every page that has a model. So why isn't the `add namespace` tag working?

Comment: Have you tried using @model IEnumerable<LangSiteMvc.Models.CalendarModel>? Also, why are you not just using MVC's scaffolding feature instead of doing everything manually?

Comment: Are you sure you have added given namespaces to `web.config` in your `Views` folder?